# Django Regex Adding /? to Urls.py Breaks Static Link

Tags: python, regex, django

Trying to build my regex to facilitate the most possible entries:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?i)(a|b|c)-kit$', path),
    url(r'^(?i)a-kit/(a|b|c)$', path),
    ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The "/?" at the end breaks my static file location. The template is selected properly, but the static files path gets broken, because it adds the current page directory as root. Here is the relevant part of the  settings.py

```
  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')

  STATIC_URL = 'MySite/static/'
```

My question is how and why this occurs, and any links or suggestions to fix will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully resolve my issues by following the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20817575/2567455)

Answer (score 1):

Then end slash is automatically taken care of by django. From the [documentation for `APPEND_SLASH`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/settings/#append-slash):

> `APPEND_SLASH`
>
> Default: `True`
>
> When set to `True`, if the request URL does not match any of the
>   patterns in the URLconf and it doesn’t end in a slash, an HTTP
>   redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended. Note that
>   the redirect may cause any data submitted in a POST request to be
>   lost.
>
> The `APPEND_SLASH` setting is only used if `CommonMiddleware` is
>   installed.

Comment: This solved my trailing slash problem, but unfortunately the same problem is presenting itself in another form. I believe it has something to do with my static setup. I added some more code, please have a look.

Comment: Are you running `DEBUG = True`?

Comment: Yes, of course, the problem is the template loads, but all my static links get 404 because it adds the previous directory to the path. No debug to go off of. Any ideas?

Comment: It breaks on the second link I added to the url.py. All my static sources end up becoming `a-kit/mysite/static/css/normalize.css`

Comment: If you have `DEBUG = True` (and using `runserver`) then you don't need to add the static file handler; remove that from your `urls.py`.

Comment: I removed it and now static files do not work anywhere on the site. This is frustrating because the paths are correct I am about to give up and just hard code it.

Comment: Change your `STATIC_URL` to `/static/`; and please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/) because you are doing things incorrectly. You only set `STATIC_ROOT` when you are about to deploy (its not even required).

Comment: I've read the documentation like 1000 times, I had it set up like that and the only way I could get it to work is by doing what I have posted. I will continue to try. Adding the static_root is the only way I have been able to get it to work at all with the exception of the original problem I posted. If I change the Static_Url to /static/ and remove the Static_Root it does not serve the files. I am using nitrous.io with django version 1.5.