# Forward Slash Breaking Url.py

Tags: python, django, nitrousio

I am a newbie please be gentle. I am using Nitrous.io and Django 1.5. I am experiencing some weird occurrences and was looking for some explanation. I am not sure if it is a piece of Middle-ware or my newbism that is causing problems (my money is on my newbism). Sorry for the blue squiggles I was not sure what the policy is on this sorta thing.

This is my urls.py:

```
 urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^church$', church),
 ) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Before you tell me that I do not need to add that static snippet please note that is the only way I could get my static files to be properly served.

This is the relevant portions of my settings.py:

```
 DEBUG = True
 INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'StructureBuilder', #this is the name of my app
'django.contrib.admin',
 )

 MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  )


 STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
 STATIC_URL = 'MySite/static/'
```

Before you tell me that my `STATIC_URL` is wrong or that I do not need the `STATIC_ROOT`, please note this is the only way I have been able to get my static files to be properly served.

**This is what happens:**

If I add a forward slash to my urlpatterns for example `url(r'^church/$', church),` the regex checks out however none of my static files are loaded.

[image]
[image]

If I remove the forwards slash (eg. `url(r'^church$', church),` and reload the page, I will get a 404 error because of the forward slash. I was under the impression that common middle-ware (which I have installed) handled the forward slash [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20779447/2567455)

[image]

Removing the forward slash loads the page perfectly:

[image]

[image]

Obviously, this is not desired. I can work with it, but this happens with any forward slash not just when it is at the end of the regex. This becomes a problem because it will also add the current page to the beginning of all my static files.

**My Questions:** Why is the common middle-ware not properly handling the forward slash? What exactly is wrong with my static file serving configuration that the above way is the only way I am able to get it to work?

Comment: How does your template look like?

Comment: paste a sample line of your template where you call your static files, also try to append a / in your static URL settings.

Comment: Rather than the images, it would be much more helpful if you post the example static urls that are being generated in each case `/church/****/static/css/normalize.css` is one, but I don't know what the working one looks like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With no slash in front of your `STATIC_URL` the browser is treating it as a relative URL.

As you can see in your screenshot of `normalize.css` failing /church/ is prefixed to your `STATIC_URL`. Where in the other requests where these files are working, /church/ is not there.

Change:

```
STATIC_URL = 'MySite/static/'
```

to

```
STATIC_URL = '/MySite/static/'
```

This will cause the requests of the static content to  never be influenced by slashes in your URL as they will always start @ the root of the server.

Comment: I am amazed that this one single forward slash has given me so much difficulty. This was in fact the problem and has successfully fixed all other issues with the forward slash I have been having.